# Debug Node (>=6.3) from a docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, remote-debugging, node-inspector

I have a docker container which uses pm2 to run node like so:

```
#process.yml
apps:

  - script: ./index.js
    name: client
    watch: true
    args: --inspect

 #Dockerfile

 CMD pm2-docker process.yml
```

As I could read in [that post](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27): The node inspector has arrived in the core of node.js and running a script like so:

```
node --inspect <somescript.js>
```

gives some output on the commandline like that: `chrome-devtools://…` and navigating to that url in chrome, will fire up node-inspector.

How can I do that for a node instance that lives inside a container, but should be debugged from the host.

*UPDATE*

I could manage to start the debug process by changing two things:

1. `node_args: --inspect=localhost:9080`
2. `docker run ... -p 9080:9080`

But that brings up one Problem: The URL to use is displayed on the commandline right after `node --inspect=... ...` is executed, but when running the docker container that information goes down to the logs somewhere. So how can I access the url from there?

Comment: I would not use pm2 with docker, because docker itself has these features

Comment: So what would you use instead? Right now I have three node processes for that container which all should run.

Comment: A normal container can be started/stoped/restarted, you can view logs and stats, a container can automaticly restart if it fails and you can do healthchecks. Docker Swarm can scale (start the same image multiple times) with a loadbalancer in front of them and do zero downtime updates. In my option docker has all the features of pm2 and is better suited if you anyway use docker

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply publish the required with -p 9229:9229 or

```
ports: 
  - 9229:9229
```

in the docker-compose, and then start it with pm2 and the `--inspect` arg or directly with `node --inspect index`.
The url will then be printed out and you can simply use it in chrome like without docker.

To find that line afterwards you can use

```
docker-compose logs service-name | grep chrome-devtools
```

or

```
docker logs container-id 2>&1 | grep chrome-devtools
```